# 'CCFadeTransition' undeclared

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to Cocos2d and using 0.99.5 with CCFadeTransition but showing error as 'CCFadeTransition' undeclared   (first use in this function)

My code.

```
CCFadeTransition* transitionScene = [CCFadeTransition transitionWithDuration:3 scene:scene withColor:ccRED];
//CCFadeTRTransition* transitionScene = [CCFadeTRTransition transitionWithDuration:3 scene:scene];
//CCRotoZoomTransition* transitionScene = [CCRotoZoomTransition transitionWithDuration:3 scene:scene];
//CCShrinkGrowTransition* transitionScene = [CCShrinkGrowTransition transitionWithDuration:3 scene:scene];
//CCTurnOffTilesTransition* transitionScene = [CCTurnOffTilesTransition transitionWithDuration:3 scene:scene];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:transitionScene];
```

Only my cocos2d recognize CCDirector but not CCFadeTransition, CCFadeTRTransition, CCRotoZoomTransition, CCShrinkGrowTransition, CCShrinkGrowTransition, CCTurnOffTilesTransition ?? Why is this so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some names have been changed in 0.99.5 version

You want to use CCTransitionFade instead

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_transition_fade.html

Comment: Thanks bro , but now it is showing Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Comment: @user: I suggest you to ask a new question because now you have another problem

Comment: @user366584 that sounds like you are missing some internal files.  Might want to reinstall xcode an/or cocos2D.  You should probably post a new question like Andrew said first though.